# Triggersend issue to update data to all subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud

we need to update data into triggersend de and allsubscribers.in my case we are able to add data into triggersend de and email is triggering correctly. when we check in all subscribers for that subscriber email address and subscriber key is added, on other 3 different fields data is not added in allsubscribers.

**Note:**
In de we have 5 fields email,subscriberkey,city,zip,path.
same fields are there in allsubscribers also. data is updating in triggersend de on all 5 fields, but in allsubscribers only email and subscriberkey is added.

Is there any way to add other 3 fields data into allsubscribers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either serialize the Subscriber Attributes as Profile Attributes in All Subscribers list, **or** a Triggered Send DE. Not both.

If you are using a Triggered Send DE (you mentioned that you are), Marketing Cloud will first check to see if the fields exist in it, and if they don't then it will check if they exist as Subscriber Profile Attributes.

If you need to update the Profile Attributes, remove these fields from your Triggered Send DE first.

Comment: That's great to hear that your issue is resolved. Please can you either accept my answer, or add your own answer and accept it, for the benefit of others (so this does not remain an unanswered question).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the box to Update Subscribers in the trigger?

[image]

Comment: yes Harley only email and subscriberkey is added. other fields are not added

Comment: any other suggestions

Comment: the code iam using is below